# Замена NA в столбцах

Tags: csv, r

Производится работа с файлом формата csv, в которой есть несколько столбцов. Файл записан в объект footval. В  некоторых столбцах есть неопознанные значения NA. Допустим было подсчитано среднее значение в этом столбце без NA

`x <- mean(football$goals, na.rm=TRUE)`

Как произвести замену всех NA в этом столбце на х или на другое желаемое число?  И можно ли через цикл, имея все средние значения, заменить все NA по соответствующим столбцам?

Только начинаю знакомство с R. Буду рад любой помощи. Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: [множество вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25835643/4827341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из многочисленных вариантов решения данной задачи:

```r
# Находим столбцы с количественными переменными
cols <- names(df)[sapply(df, is.numeric)]
# Считаем средние значения по найденными столбцам
avg <- colMeans(df[cols], na.rm = TRUE)
for (col in cols) {
  # Условие наличия хотя бы одного пропущенного значения в столбце
  if (anyNA(col)) {
    # Находим индексы пропущенных значений
    idx <- which(is.na(df[[col]]))
    # Заменяем найденные пропущенные значения на среднее
    df[[col]][idx] <- avg[col]
  }
}
```